# Is it possible to have a segmentation fault due to an x-server?

Tags: c, windows, segmentation-fault, sdl, xserver

For a school project, I'm building a GUI, but I wanted to work on this project at home, and as I only own a windows computer, I installed a x-server (to use with the Windows Subsystem for Linux) : "VcXsrv Windows X Server".

For some of my test programs it worked perfectly, but for one, I've got a segmentation fault (core dumped).

So I tried to debug with gdb (which doesn't neet the x-server to work), but... it worked perfectly...

So here's my question : is it possible to get a segmentation fault due to the x-server ?

Comment: Linux is free to install. Why not try there?

Comment: It's not unheard of, but rare and depends on the GUI framework that you're using. It's certainly possible if you're doing some very weird stuff like, for example, talking to the X server directly alongside the GUI library. Otherwise it's most likely a bug in the library.

Comment: @VaughanHilts I haven't so much place in my computer and I need Windows for video editing

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I'm usind the SDL library

Comment: If you can debug it in gdb, then I guess the program itself does not use X?  In that case, what do you need an X server for?

Comment: Technically, any software your program interacts with can cause a runtime error.   However, practically, if some program of yours starts failing after installing an X server, it almost certainly indicates a fault in your program. The mechanism would be your program tromping on some memory location that it shouldn't, the X-server installation somehow changes what is at that memory location when your program is run, which allows the OS to now detect your program doing something untoward and terminate it. In other words, the problem is almost certainly in your program, not the X server.

Comment: As message says, you should have core dump (usually named `core.some_numeric_pid`). You can load that into gdb with `gdb /path/to/your_program /path/to/core_dump` to inspect where it failed.

Answer (score 2):

If your program fails with a segmentation fault then the root cause is almost certain to be in your program, not the environment.  It is possible, however, that the undefined behavior of your program that manifests as a segfault in one environment manifests differently in another environment or with a different configuration.  In that sense, you could say that an X server could "cause" a segfault, but characterizing it that way does not in any way let your program off the hook.

It's not uncommon that UB manifests differently when a program is run under a debugger than when run directly.  This goes along with being "undefined".  If you're seeing segfaults then it's not unreasonable to turn to a debugger, but a more likely tool for characterizing the problem would be a memory-usage analyzer, such as Valgrind.

Comment: I used Valgrind, but it doesn't say anything. I tried today at my school on a linux OS directly, and it doesn't show any seg fault.
I must admit I'm confused